# How to convert color code into actual color

Tags: css, angular, uitableview, mat-table

I'm using Angular material with Angular6 in my project. What I want to do is convert color codes which stored in the database into actual colors in my `mat-table`.

Currently, my table is as follows,
[image]

This is how I'm getting visible columns data from my `component.ts` file,

```
getIssueCategory() {
  this.IssueService.getAllIssueCategories().subscribe(result => {
      this.issueCategoryDTOList = result.reverse();

      //updating data source
      this.updatingDataSource(result);

      this.IssueService.issueCategoryDTOList = result;
    }
  );
}

get visibleColumns() {
  return this.displayedColumns.filter(column => column.visible).map(column => column.property);
}

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

The color column in my HTML file is as follows,

```
<!-- color Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="color">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="color" style="max-width: 25%; min-width: 25%;">COLOR
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 25%; min-width: 25%;">
        {{element.color}}
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Finally to getting understand easier I have designed my expected output using photoshop,
[image]

PS: In my database, the colors are stored as color codes.

Comment: Have you tried `[style.background-color]="element.color"`?

Comment: Yes as the accepted answer I have tried it and it worked perfectly for me. Thank you @Reactgular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create a square using css and apply your `color` dynamically to the element as the `background-color`

In place of where you were displaying the color in the table, add a div which we will style as a square using css. Then set the background color to it like below.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="color">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="color" style="max-width: 25%; min-width: 25%;">COLOR</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <div class="square" [style.background-color]="element.color">
    </div>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

In your css

```css
.square {
  /* Specify the dimensions of your square here */
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

Comment: this answer workes for me and since I think this is simple than others I accepted the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do something like -

```
<!-- color Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="color">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="color" style="max-width: 25%; min-width: 25%;">COLOR
   </mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 25%; min-width: 25%;">
     <div style="width: 15px; height: 15px" [style.background-color]="element.color">/div>
   </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Or perhaps a better way would be to turn it into a component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-color-swatch',
  template: `<div [style.background-color]="colorCode"></div>`,
  styles: ['div { height: 15px; width: 15px }']
})
export class ColorSwatchComponent {

  @Input colorCode: string;

}
```

Then -

```
<app-color-swatch [color]="element.color"></app-color-swatch>
```

Comment: The answer is working but I can't understand the use of  '@Input colorCode: string;' and '<app-color-swatch [color]="element.color"></app-color-swatch>'

Comment: If you can explain it would be very helpfull

Comment: The `@Input` field is just a way of passing data into the component. So you use `@Input myProperty: string` then assign a value to the property by using `[myProperty]="someValue"`. More info here https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input matInput type="color" value="color from Database">
```

Example:

```
<input matInput type="color" value="#904A91">
```